# Angularjs pass ng-repeat checkbox value undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, checkbox, undefined

This question asked already but that not solve my issue.

Am trying to pass `checkbox` value to **controller** but i got `undefined` message.
Am beginner in `Angularjs`.

This is my `HTML` code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="addForm" novalidate ng-submit="addData(addForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="directories in formData.getMainDirectories">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="directories.main_directories_id.selected" value="{{directories.id}}"><span>  {{directories.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" button-spinner="loading" ng-disabled="loading">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My `.js` code:

```
$scope.addData = function(form)
{
    $scope.errors = [];
    alert(form.main_directories_id); // alert here
    if(form.$valid)
    {
        $rootScope.loading = true;

        webServices.upload('create', $scope.formData).then(function(getData) {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            if (getData.status == 200) {
                $sessionStorage.successmessage = getData.data.message;
                localStorage.directory = '';
                $scope.goback();
            } else if (getData.status == 401) {
                $scope.errors = utility.getError(getData.data.message);
                $scope.showerrors();
            } else {
                $rootScope.$emit("showerror", getData);
            }
        });
    }
}

$scope.getMainDirectories = function()
    {
        webServices.get('getMainDirectories').then(function(getData) 
        {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            if (getData.status == 200) 
            {
                $scope.formData.getMainDirectories = getData.data;
            } else {
                $rootScope.$emit("showerror", getData);
            }
            //console.log(getData.data);
        });
    }
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: what is `formData.getMainDirectories`

Comment: @quirimmo: Please check my question i just updated `formData.getMainDirectories` is my fetch data's

Comment: you are missing to call the function: this `ng-repeat="directories in formData.getMainDirectories"` should be `ng-repeat="directories in formData.getMainDirectories()"`

Comment: @quirimmo: If i change `formData.getMainDirectories` to `formData.getMainDirectories()` data's not receiving

Comment: sorry, misunderstanding due to the same name you used for the function in the `$scope` and the property of `formData`

Comment: @quirimmo: Okay bro how can i pass `ng-model="directories.main_directories_id.selected"` value to my controller.

Comment: the checkbox in angularjs has two values: `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185823/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-quirimmo).

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: This will do : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="directories.main_directories_id.selected">

I hope the value in directories.main_directories_id.selected is boolean.

Comment: @subodhkalika: No again undefined values :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solutions

```
$scope.addData = function(form)
{
    $scope.errors = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.formData.getMainDirectories.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.formData.getMainDirectories[i].Selected) 
        {
            $scope.formData.main_directories_id.push($scope.formData.getMainDirectories[i].id);
        }
    }

    //console.log($scope.formData.main_directories_id);

    if(form.$valid)
    {
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        webServices.upload('create', $scope.formData).then(function(getData) {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            if (getData.status == 200) 
            {
                $sessionStorage.successmessage = getData.data.message;
                localStorage.directory = '';
                $scope.goback();
            } else if (getData.status == 401) {
                $scope.errors = utility.getError(getData.data.message);
                $scope.showerrors();
            } else {
                $rootScope.$emit("showerror", getData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="directories in formData.getMainDirectories">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="directories.Selected" /><span>  {{directories.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.